# What will happen if I add 2GB more RAM with 4GB in Windows 7 32-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 32-bit

I already have 4 GB ram but only 2.43 GB usable in my Windows 7 32-bit OS. If I install 2 GB more with 4 GB of old RAM, is it possible to do that to increase the usable RAM size?

[image]

Comment: No. 32 bit bit Windows is max usable 4GM RAM.

Comment: [Windows 7 Ultimate \[64bits\] - 12GB installed but 3,18GB usable](//superuser.com/a/872355)

Answer (score 2):

A 32-bit operating system cannot address more than 4GB of memory. Putting additional memory into such a computer will be a waste. However, if you upgrade to a 64-bit operating system, additional memory will be found and used.

The link in David Postill's second comment above is quite useful.